# How I pass another parameter (text) in this ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to post canvas image data and a test using ajax. but I can't. How I achieve this? these are the following code:

## Ajax call:

```
$("#connect").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var imgData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var message = $("#msg").val();
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('imagedata', imgData);
    data.append('msg', message);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'photoappcode.php', false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
    xhr.send(data);
    });
```

## PHP Code:

```
$imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

if(!empty($imageData)){
  $fileNo = time();
  $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
  $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
  $fp = fopen("images/image_".$fileNo.".png", 'wb' );
  fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
  $path_parts =  basename($fp);
  fclose( $fp );
}

echo $imageData;

echo $msg;
```

Here I couldn't get the value from ajax call. please help.

Comment: as always, press F12 on your browser and check the network tab for what values are being sent in the HTML request.

Comment: There's no `application/upload` content type. It should be `multipart/form-data`. I think the browser will do this automatically when you send a `FormData` object.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, it's deprecated. It's also wrong for this. Just use `$_POST['imagedata']`.

Comment: -----------------------------339128268468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imagedata"

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAJYCAY..................................................
-----------------------------339128268468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="msg"

logic
-----------------------------339128268468--

Comment: thes is the parameter passed by ajax..

Comment: This is happening when i change the content type to multipart/form-data. and use $_POST['imagedata'].

Comment: result:  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>